How to simplify multiple functions with same logic but different parameter type?
void functionA(A a){
  for(auto x: vector_of_x) {
    // duplicate code, which cannot be moved to a common function
    x.abc(a);
    // some more duplicate code, which cannot be moved to a common function
  }
}

void functionB(B b){
  for(auto x: vector_of_x) {
    // duplicate code, which cannot be moved to a common function
    x.def(b);
    // some more duplicate code, which cannot be moved to a common function
  }
}

The duplicate code in functionA and functionB is quite a lot, so I'm looking to remove duplicate code. What's the best way to achieve it?

Make them templates?

@πάνταῥεῖ, Note that x.abc() and x.def() are two different functions

It seems that while there's some common code, there's also a lot of non-common code, which makes the functions very different. If anything, try to break out the common code into smaller and very specific (and possibly templated) functions.

the template parameter could be a member function pointer. Or just a lambda for greater generality.

@RaymondChen, could you pls elaborate? I'm not very familiar with template usage. But this seems to be something I'm looking for

template<typename F, typename T> void function(F f, T t) { for (auto x : vector_of_x) { std::invoke(f, x, t); } } . Example usage: function(&X::abc, a); function(&X::def, b); function([](auto&& x, auto&& c) { return x.abc(c.a) + x.def(c.b); }, c);

Just curious: What prevents you from moving that duplicate code ?

What's wrong with { auto pre = common(x); x.abc(a); common2(pre, x); }/ { auto pre = common(x); x.def(b); common2(pre, x); }?

You can merge functionA and functionB into a function template, where it's customizable whether abc or def gets called.
template <auto MemberFunction, typename T>
void function(T t){
  for(auto x: vector_of_x) {
    // duplicate code, which cannot be moved to a common function
    (x.*MemberFunction)(t);
    // some more duplicate code, which cannot be moved to a common function
  }
}

void functionA(A a){
  function<&A::abc>(a);
}

void functionB(B b){
  function<&B::def>(b);
}

However, member function pointers are a bit tricky syntax-wise, and they aren't very flexible.
For example, what if you wanted to also debug-print something instead of just calling A::abc?
Therefore, you would use lambda expressions (or any other invocable object) in most cases:
template <typename F>
void function(F f){
  for(auto x: vector_of_x) {
    // duplicate code, which cannot be moved to a common function
    std::invoke(f, x); // or x(f), if that's sufficient
    // some more duplicate code, which cannot be moved to a common function
  }
}

void functionA(A a){
  function( [&a](X& x) { x.abc(a); } );
}

void functionB(B b){
  function( [&b](X& x) { x.def(b); } );
}

The latter solution is very idiomatic; it's also what algorithms such as std::for_each in the standard library do.

wow, thanks for providing two different solutions!! Good learning for me.

It should be pointed out that this merges duplicate source code. Each function still exists as a complete and distinct thing in the final binary object code.

As noted in comments by Raymond Chan, supplying a lambda as an argument would provide one solution. E.g.
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

struct A {
    void abc() const { std::cout << "A::abc\n"; }
};

struct B {
    void def() const { std::cout << "B::def\n"; }
};

template <typename T>
void foo(T x, std::function<void(T)> f) {
    f(x);
}

int main() {
    A a;
    B b;

    foo<A&>(a, [&a](const auto x) { x.abc(a); });
    foo<B&>(b, [&b](const auto x) { x.def(b); });
}

Output:
A::abc
B::def


If you want to do something different for two types, that should ring a bell: function overloading. Instead of calling a member function you can do
void do_something(const auto& x,A& a) { x.abc(a); }
void do_something(const auto& x,B& b) { x.def(b); }

That leaves us with two functions, functionA and functionB, that are identical modulo one type, and that rings the next bell: function template.
template <typename T>
void functionA(T a){
  for(auto x: vector_of_x) {
    // code that is now in a common function 
    do_something(x,a);
    // more code, that is now in a common function
  }
}

If you have more types that need a do_something you can write more overloads. Or you can consider to write a trait that selects which member to call based on T.
